# List all subpackages of a package (when their classes are loaded dynamically)

Tags: java, package

I am coding on Eclipse. Under a package named `com.something.drivers` I've created a number of subpackages containing classes that implement some common interfaces. This is an example of the Driver pattern, so classes under a subpackage will be loaded dynamically from the main application. As all classes in every driver subpackage have the same name, the application can guess the qualified name of a class just after the package name.

Now I am trying to get the list of the installed drivers (subpackages under `com.something.driver` package). I don't want to maintain a manually edited list but just get it from the actually installed drivers.

I read [List all subpackages of a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893174/list-all-subpackages-of-a-package) and learn how to use `Package` class, but I've founded that  `Package.getPackage(com.something.driver).getPackages()` returns null because the classes in the subpackages under `com.something.driver` are only loaded dynamically, and one at a time.

I'm lost at this point. I suppose `Package` class is not the way but probably navigate the class tree checking with `getResource`?

Thaks in advance.

Comment: If u have a common interface, you could use google reflection to search for the classes implementing it

Comment: Thank you Henning. I suppose you mean Google Reflections. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly the best way to deal with this is to create a list as a build step (probably as a `.java` file).

`Package.getPackage` is deprecated.

`Package.getPackages` is a static method - it isn't doing what you think it's doing.

Both method use the caller's class loader, which is surprising, and isn't much use if you're "really" dynamically loading the classes.

For unloaded classes, I guess you're looking at getting hold of the class path for your class loader (assuming it's a `URLClassLoader` of some sort) and traversing directories/read jar/zip directories (or the manifest if present).

Modules may be useful - I've not really looked at them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Tom. Your idea of traversing directories from a local class path is a good idea. I will test it inside Eclipse and after exporting the application as a jar.

Comment: Modules sounds good and probably the perfect solution, but I am compiling for Java 8 and don't want to spend much time learning something new just now.