# Retrieve a list of all packages in a project with Google reflections library?

Tags: java, package, reflections

I'm talking about the [reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) lib. Is there any possibility to get a list of all packages which are included in the project where I let the code compile?

I've tried it with the following code bracket but I don't want to insert a project name.

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(/* Project name here... */);

     Set<Class<? extends Object>> allClasses = 
         reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
```

Comment: Check possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection

Comment: @AlejandroColorado I dont want to search for classes in a certain package but I want to search for **packages** in a project.

Comment: Ok, sorry! You are right!

Comment: Maybe this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185142/get-package-names-using-java-reflections?rq=1

Comment: And maybe this answer to another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4212131/1587345

Comment: and finally, maybe this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944633/java-reflection-get-list-of-packages

Answer (score 0):

Using not ronmamo/reflections but [Google Guava's ClassPath](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/reflect/ClassPath.html), one can do something like this:

```
Set<ClassInfo> classInfos = ClassPath.from(Main.class.getClassLoader()).getTopLevelClassesRecursive("org.spongepowered");
List<String> packageNames = classInfos.stream().map(classInfo -> classInfo.getPackageName()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```